How to make a potato frite hold together better? (Draniki)
I am making a Russian recipe called draniki which is a potato pancake frite, kind of like a hash brown. The potato is finely shredded and the recipe describes the "batter" as a liquid, but mine was more chunky. I do not want to really pulverize the potato into a smooth liquid because then it would loose the hash brown texture. However, as it was, it was falling apart and would not hold together when I was pan frying it.
How can I get it to hold together better?

The recipes I can find for draniki list flour and eggs among the ingredients which should be doing the job well enough. What is the recipe you are using?

The recipe is needed, as there are many ways to make potato pancakes.  I make a more a more German style shredded potato pancake, and after shredding you let it drain in a colander, but collect the liquid, then pour off the water to get the collected potato starch

@Abion47 I am using the standard approach which uses flour and eggs. The only possible difference between the standard recipe and the way I tried is that I did not fully liquify the potatoes and grated it a little more coarsely rather than finely.

It seems like the issue is that a traditional draniki isn't like a hash brown at all, so trying to follow a recipe for draniki and simply swapping in grated potatoes isn't really going to work. You would be better off following a recipe like what Joe mentioned that actually uses grated potatoes, such as Kartoffelpuffer which uses more eggs and less flour and really is basically hash browns with a small amount of thin batter.
If you want to use your current approach, you will need to make sure the potatoes are very dry before adding them to the batter. It might even be a good idea to dredge the potatoes in flour before incorporating them to help the batter stick to the potatoes. (You will want to reduce the flour content of your batter a bit to compensate as this will thicken the batter a bit, though a thicker batter might also work in your favor.)
My worry with this approach is that I'm not sure the potatoes will cook fully before the batter starts burning. So as a third option, I'd suggest cooking the pancakes in stages where you make hash browns as normal and then batter the cooked (or parcooked) hash browns.

Draniki and hash browns are not really the same thing. Draniki asks for a smooth liquid batter to make something similar to pancakes but potato flavoured, held together by flour and eggs. Hash browns need to be chunky and barely hold together due to the starch content of the potato minus its liquid. If you use a batter with hash brown-like consistency, but introduce flour and eggs, neither the flour nor the starch can properly do its job due to the liquid content of the potatoes and onions, and you'll get your current result.
You could mitigate this by marrying the two separate recipes basically half-and-half. Make the Draniki batter by finely mashing your potatoes and onions, and see if that gives you the pancake-like result you're looking for. Then to this mixture add rough-grated potato and onion which you've washed and dried thoroughly, which will give you basically pancakes with ingredients. This will give you both the desired consistency of pancakes and the crispiness of hash browns.

I did not say that draniki is the same thing as a hash brown. I said it is LIKE a hash brown so that Americans would have a general sense of what it is.

From your question it seems like you want a draniki with a hash brown-like texture, as you are hesitant to mash your potatoes further to lose texture. Neither draniki or hash browns would have that result when made per traditional recipe. I'm merely suggesting a way you could accomplish it nonetheless.
